# Angular 5 - get all component names with order number for a given page/view

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-components

Is there any way to get ***names of components*** from DOM.

for example, if my app.component.html is:

```
<div>
  <div #leftContainer>
     <app-hello></app-hello>
     <app-foo></app-foo>
  </div>
  <div #rightContainer>
    <app-bar></app-bar>
    <app-foobar><app-foobar>
  </div>
</div>
```

my **output** for GetComponents should be:

```
1-HelloComponent
2-FooComponent
3-BarComponent
4-FooBarComponent
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('leftContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) leftContainer: ViewContainerRef;
  @ViewChild('rightContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) rightContainer: ViewContainerRef;

  name = 'Angular 5';

  getComponents() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.leftContainer.length; i++) {
      console.log(this.leftContainer.get(i));
    }
  }
}
```

Complete example is at following StackBlitz url:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-weyhe4

Comment: I bet you could find the answer somewhere buried in the source code for Augury - https://github.com/rangle/augury

Comment: Not natively ..